# Cannot insert a NULL value into column x using update statement in Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift, inner-join

I am trying to update several rows using output of the other query , having the condition when nombregestorevento LIKE 'karate%'. However I don't understand the reason why Redshift is throwing the  error
**ERROR: Cannot insert a NULL value into column nombregestorevento**
while there is not any null in the output of any of the queries.

Here is the query:

```
begin;    
update lu_gestor_evento
    set nombregestorevento = (select nombregestorevento from lu_gestor_evento_pro a12 
     where a12.id_gestorevento = lu_gestor_evento.id_gestorevento)
     WHERE lu_gestor_evento.nombregestorevento LIKE 'karate%';

 commit;
```

I had checked both tables and I can't find any Null in any of the tables. How can I change the query to not throwing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error does indicate that your subquery returns a `null` value. If there are no `null` values in the source table, then it means that the subquery returned *no rows* - which reads as a `null` value in the `set` clause.

In other words, the error happens when the `id_gestorevento` of target table `lu_gestor_evento` does not exist in source table `lu_gestor_evento_pro`.

Probably, you want to update matching rows only, and leave others untouched. If so, in Redshift we can use the `update/from` syntax:

```sql
update lu_gestor_evento e
set nombregestorevento = ep.nombregestorevento
from lu_gestor_evento_pro ep
where ep.id_gestorevento = e.id_gestorevento
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB for your reply. I did  the join between two tables and it returns many rows. I exactly wanted to change just the common rows. I don't believe that it return no rows.  By the way, I am going to try the query you have provided..